# How to do something like: "Your number is " + number " ." in C++?

Tags: c++, string, cout

I recently started C++, moving from JavaScript, so I'm a little bit confused.

I'm trying to make a number guessing game, and  my actual error is something like:

```
main.cpp:14:67: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char [2]’ to binary ‘operator+’
   cout << "Perfect, now your playing with numbers up to " + range + "."
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
$ g++ main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:14:67: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char [2]’ to binary ‘operator+’
   cout << "Perfect, now your playing with numbers up to " + range + "."
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

I have no idea if it helps, but I'm going to attach my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void startGame(int random);
int generateNo(int range);

int main() {
  int range;
  cout << "WELCOME TO  NUMBER GUESSING GAME!" << endl;
  cout << "The calculator is going to generate a random number and you'll have to guess it!" << endl;
  cout << "Please enter the range  of numbers you want to play (ex: 10)" << endl;
  cin >> range;
  int solution = generateNo(range);
  cout << "Perfect, now your playing with numbers up to " + range + "."
  cout << "GOOD LUCK :)" << endl;

  startGame(solution);

  return 0;
}

int generateNo(int range) {
  return rand() % range + 1;
}

void startGame(int random) {
  int inputNo;

  cin >> inputNo;

  for( int a = 0; ; a++) {
    if(inputNo == random) {
      cout << "Congrats! You've guessed the number!" << endl;
      break;
    } else if(inputNo > random) {
      cout << "Hooolly! WHAT'S with this giant number" << endl;
      startGame(random);
      break;
    } else {
      cout << "Good number, but had your little brain considered to make it bigger!?" << endl;
      startGame(random);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can chain calls to `<<`:

```
cout << "Perfect, now your playing with numbers up to " << range << ".";
```

If you want to first build a string (no reason to do that here), you first need to build a string:

```
std::string text = std::string{"Perfect, now ..."} + std::to_string(range) + ".";
std::cout << text;
```

In your code you are trying to add a string literal (type is `char[N]`) with an integer. There is no `operator+` to concatenate an integer to a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't overload the `+` operator between all the arbitrary types, and doesn't implicitly convert everything to strings when you try to print it out. Luckily, for all the built-in types, you could just write them to the output stream using the `<<` operator (and override it for your own types):

```cpp
cout << "Perfect, now your playing with numbers up to " 
     << range // Note the use of "<<" and not of "+"
     << "."
     << "GOOD LUCK :)"
     << endl;
```